# MySql every derived table must have its own alias. Even when all have

Tags: mysql, sql

```
UPDATE  likesd a
    INNER JOIN (
select id, perCent, rank
from
(
    select id, perCent, elmTotals 
    , @curRank :=   
        case 
           when @prevParent = parent then
               case 
                   when @prevCent = perCent then @curRank
                   else @curRank + 1
               end
           else 1
        end rank
    , @prevParent := parent
    , @prevCent := perCent
    from 
    (
        select child.id, child.perCent, child.parent
        from likesd parent
        inner join likesd child
           on child.parent = parent.id and child.country = parent.country
        where parent.type = 3
        order by parent.id, child.perCent desc
    ) b
    cross join (SELECT @curRank := 0, @prevParent := null, @prevCent := null) c
) d ) ON a.country = d.country and a.id = d.id
    SET a.rank = d.rank
    WHERE a.type = 10;
```

In the above sql, I get the error: `/* SQL Error (1248): Every derived table must have its own alias */` even when all my derived tables have an alias. Everything works ok without the update wrapped around the main sql. But when I add an update I get this error.

The end result is to update the column `rank` with the `rank` from the select. It's only the update that's giving problems. There big select inside it is fine.

Heres the table below, and here's a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac996/7) with some data

**Main Table**

```
"id"    "type"  "parent"    "country"   "votes" "perCent" "rank"
"24"    "1"     "1"         "US"        "35"    "0"
"25"    "3"     "24"        "US"        "35"    "0"
"26"    "10"    "25"        "US"        "15"    "50.00"
"27"    "10"    "25"        "US"        "10"    "33.33"
"28"    "10"    "25"        "US"        "10"    "33.33"

"29"    "1"     "1"         "US"        "50"    "0"
"30"    "3"     "29"        "US"        "50"    "0"
"31"    "10"    "30"        "US"        "20"    "40.00"
"32"    "10"    "30"        "US"        "15"    "25.00"
"33"    "10"    "30"        "US"        "15"    "35.00"
```

Comment: Is sqlfiddle down for anyone else?

Comment: @Mihai yes it is down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE  likesd a
    INNER JOIN (
select id, perCent, rank
from
(
    select id, perCent, elmTotals 
    , @curRank :=   
        case 
           when @prevParent = parent then
               case 
                   when @prevCent = perCent then @curRank
                   else @curRank + 1
               end
           else 1
        end rank
    , @prevParent := parent
    , @prevCent := perCent
    from 
    (
        select child.id, child.perCent, child.parent
        from likesd parent
        inner join likesd child
           on child.parent = parent.id and child.country = parent.country
        where parent.type = 3
        order by parent.id, child.perCent desc
    ) b
    cross join (SELECT @curRank := 0, @prevParent := null, @prevCent := null) c
) d )f ON a.country = d.country and a.id = d.id
    SET a.rank = d.rank
    WHERE a.type = 10;
```

Comment: I was posting the `)f` as `) missingTableAlias` on the comments. You get it first :)

Comment: In the on clause, should it now be a. with f. or a. with d.? I keep getting `Unknown column 'd.country' in 'on clause`

Comment: I think it should be a.country = f.country and a.id = f.id

Comment: Just one small thing, should I also specify the join conditions even in the `WHERE` clause to make things safer?

Comment: I don't think putting the conditions also on where will make things safer.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing one alias:

```
cross join (SELECT @curRank := 0, @prevParent := null, @prevCent := null) c
) d ) ON a.country = d.country and a.id = d.id
     ^ Here
```